# Using Firebase for my chat application, when I send messages really fast, some messages don't display

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I send messages really fast, like one letter messages. Some messages do not load to the receiver of the messages. I am using child added to observe messages added. The messages are definitely stored in Firebase. But child added isn't detecting them. How can I make sure that they are always detected?

When they are sent too fast some of them are missing?

```
let ref2 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.userdefaults.objectForKey("FBid") as! String).child(friendID)

ref2.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot2) in let messageId = snapshot2.key let 

  messagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(messageId) messagesRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in 

    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else {return} 

    print(dictionary["text"]) 

  }) 

})
```